# Unable to retreive All the LWC on VsCode

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I tried creating projects on VScode with or without manifest and updating metadata but cant retreive the LWC of an Unmanaged Package.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be the case that you need to add a reference to the specific package in your package.xml, alongside the wildcard (*) that's collecting the LWCs that you *can* see. For help amending the package.xml, I'd refer to the Packages section of [this official samples doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm). I'm guessing it'd look like this:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Your_Unmanaged_Package_Namespace</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
<version>47.0</version>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too

```
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle
```